# Counting :- Inclusion exclusion principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Out of a group of $21$ persons, $9$ eat vegetables, $10$ eat fish and $7$ eat eggs. $5$ persons eat all three. How many persons eat at least two out of the three dishes?

My approach:-
$N(A∪B∪C)=N(A)+N(B)+N(C)−N(A∩B)−N(A∩C)−N(B∩C)+N(A∩B∩C)$

$21=9+10+7−N(A∩B)−N(A∩C)−N(B∩C)+5$

$N(A∩B)+N(A∩C)+N(B∩C)=10$

Now the LHS has counted $N(A∩B∩C)$ three times, so I will remove it two times as:-

Number of persons eating at least two dishes $=N(A∩B+B∩C+A∩C ) - 2*N(A∩B∩C)
                                              =10-2*5
                                              =0$

Now it contradicts the questions that there are $5$ eating all three dishes.

Is this anything wrong in my approach?

Comment: @David: you are right, my mistake: I am going to cancel it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see there is something wrong with your approach, but also the question does not have enough information to give a definite answer.

Your mistake is to assume that $N(A\cup B\cup C)=21$.  However presumably the $21$ people may include some who eat neither vegetables nor fish nor eggs: if there are $n$ such people then you should have
$$N(A\cup B\cup C)=21-n\ .$$
If you now follow your method you should get the number of people you want also to be $n$.  And since $n$ is not known, the problem cannot be answered.  In fact as you point out, the answer must be at least $5$, so we know that $n\ge5$.  You can find solutions by trial and error with $n=5,6,7,8,9,10$, so any of these is a possible answer.

Comment: Yes,you are right.Thank you!!

Comment: I check some where online.The answer given is X ,where  5≤X≤11.I dont understand how can we get upper bound

Comment: We have $N(A\cup B\cup C)\ge N(B)=10$ so $n\le11$.  In fact by more careful work, or by using a Venn diagram, one can show that $N(A\cup B\cup C)\ge11$ so $n\le10$.